# Pass variable through button laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a product page with various products. A user can write a review about the products.

I want to pass the product listing id (product_id) through so when a user adds a review, the product id is added to the database with the review.

```
Database one (products): product_id and description
Database two (reviews): product_id, user_id and review
```

I am able to pass through user_id through $reviews->user_id = auth()->user()->id; I dont want to hardcode the button and pass through the prouct_id like that, is there any other way?

Comment: make you question more clear.

Comment: Can you show us your blade and route please?

Answer (score 0):

Normally for review we don't need to reload the page when posting data to controller. So as my idea you should have an ajax call to controller with data posting you want in this case you will need to user_id, product_id, review

```
  $.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{{URL::route("route_name")}}',
    data: {
      'user_id': value,
      'product_id': value,
      'review': value
    },
    success(data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

I am not sure it is fixed you problem or not. Just my idea.